What is the ARMAX model specification of the following economic setting?
I am currently doing a project estimating electricity prices in France, however, my modelling skills are lacking. I have hourly data on spot prices, which are determined per separate hour, one day prior to delivery. I am using an ARMA regression in Stata to model prices, but electricity market mechanisms complicate the model specification. The dependent variable is (trivially) price, the independent variables are some market characteristics such as the amount of wind energy generation.
In my model, I have included the 24th and the 168th autoregressive lags of the variable price, since those correspond to the price at the 'same hour' one day and one week prior, respectively. Including the first lag of price would not make a lot of sense in terms of economic theory because, most of the time, the price at time $t-1$ was determined in tandem with the price at $t$.
I also want to include an MA term, but I do not know how to determine it. I have read literature on similar topics and often, the same lag is used for both the AR component and the MA part (and some papers argue that it takes care of seasonality in a sense). However, running an ARMAX model with MA lag 24 and 168 in Stata (arima price windenergy ... ... ..., ma(24,168)) takes days to run without seeing even the first iteration occurring. Hence, I am not sure what MA lag(s) to include. The following link depicts my ACF and PACF plots; https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12ypoDX092AamYdwXkkzODjnmebf0-1wg?usp=sharing
The project has specified that the 24th and 168th AR lags must be included so that is given as a fact. What MA terms should I specify, provided the information above? Is there a solution to Stata running so slow? Or should I use Stata to specify a SARIMAX model (or an alternative model) that does in essence exactly what I am trying to do now?
Thank you in advance!

You may consult Rob J. Hyndman's blog and textbook ("Forecasting: Principles and Practice") entries on long seasonal periods. (Google them.) This will explain why ARMA is not great in such situations and what to use instead. See also some of these threads.
